# A map within a map vs split the key of type String, which will perform faster?

Tags: java, string, collections, split, hashmap

I have a map as `Map<String,String>` 
and the entries are like `map.put("c_09.01--x28", "OTH")`. In this I use split the key and use the `x28` to change it to `OTH`.  So my question is whether I should use split operation or use map within a map and `map.put("c_09.01", newMap)` where newMap will have `map.put("x28", 'OTH')`. Which one will give me better performance? sample code where I have used that is

```
for (Entry<String,String> sheetEntry : this.getSheetCD().getUserDefinedSheetCodeMap().entrySet()) {
    String Key = sheet.getKey().split("--")[1];
    int sheetIndex = template.getSheetIndex(sheetKey);
    if(sheetEntry.getKey().toUpperCase().startsWith(getFileName()){ 
        String newSheetName = sheetEntry.getValue();
        template.setSheetName(sheetIndex, newSheetName);    
        }
}
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. Regards.

Comment: why don't you try it and let us know the results?

Comment: it is used in a project where I can't run it separately. but it will be the first thing I get back to my place.

Comment: How big would the map ever get? Because  if it will never be big too big you will not be able to tell the difference. But it is a simple benchmark to perform. But if you read at your post will know the cost of each one. Also how frequently will you perform the gets?

Comment: First, there will not be more than 10k values, and second ,I will be doing this operation once in the whole transaction.

Comment: I think you should use the version that produces clearer, easier to maintain and more understandable code. If you later realize that you need to tune the performance you can still do that. But nothing is more frustration than unnecessary complex and hard to understand code that got written like tha because the coder thought "it would have better performance"

Comment: @911DidBush I am totally with you on this.

Comment: I am with @911DidBush. Also, how many times a day you are performing this transaction? Are you bc'ing the map after he transaction is over?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Split operation because if you are using split operation so at the time of `iteration` the object from map that time you can `iterate` the value using single `forEach loop`.

**Sample Code**

```
String str[] = "c_09.01--x28".split("--")[1];
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(str, "OTH");

        for(Map.Entry eMap:map.entrySet()){             //single forEach loop
            System.out.println("Key : "+eMap.getKey());
            System.out.println("Value : "+eMap.getValue());
        }
```

**Output**

```
Key : x28
Value : OTH
```

If you use `map.put("c_09.01", newMap);` this one, so you need to `iterate` two times. Like first you need to `iterate` `newMap` using key `c_09.01` than again you need to `iterate` `OTH` using key `x28`.

**Sample Code**

```
String str[] = "c_09.01--x28".split("--");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(str[1], "OTH");

        Map<String, Map> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put(str[0], map);

        for(Map.Entry eMap : map1.entrySet()){            //First forEach Loop
            System.out.println("Key : "+eMap.getKey());  //getiing key "c_09.01"
            Map<String, String> map2 = (Map<String, String>) eMap.getValue(); //getting map and need to be cast because it return object type
            for(Map.Entry eMap1 : map2.entrySet()){      // Second forEach loop 
                System.out.println("Key Using map.put(String, newMAp) : "+eMap1.getKey());
                System.out.println("ValueUsing map.put(String, newMAp) : "+eMap1.getValue());
            }
        }
```

**Output**

```
Key : c_09.01
Key Using map.put(String, newMAp) : x28
ValueUsing map.put(String, newMAp) : OTH
```

So i guess you should use split operation.